# Embedded board with apache

Tags: linux, compiling, embedded

I'm working on a Davinci DSP ARM embedded board. The board itself is the Texas Instruments 816X/389X EVM. I'm currently trying to get apache working on the board. The problem is that the SDK for the board is extremely basic and doesn't include 'make' or any update manager like RPM, yum, or apt-get. So I'm having a hard time getting it to work.

I compiled apache on my host machine, which is connected through minicom to the target. I have G++ Sourcery installed, but don't have any experience with it. So, when I took the compiled files to the target, I ended up with the error:

line 1: syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

I'm assuming that I did something wrong during the compile, but I'm not really sure because I'm normally a hardware designer and not a software guy.

Comment: [njozwiak's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42984) explains why the executable isn't working. The reason you're getting that message is that since the kernel didn't recognize the executable's format, it tried invoking a shell to run this as a script, and the error you're seeing is from the shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are compiling something for another system, it needs to be cross-compiled to that architecture. Most likely your host is an x86. The TI is an ARM. The instruction set isn't the same. You need to setup a cross toolchain to compile apache with an ARM version of g++. TI should have included cross tools with the EVM so that's the best place to start looking. Otherwise, you can build your own toolchain (http://kegel.com/crosstool/).